# Debugging in JRuby 9000

Tags: ruby, debugging, jruby, pry, byebug

What is the best way to debug in JRuby 9000? Pry and Byebug are both MRI-dependent. All the JRuby info that I have found seem to be only for pre-9k, and are not working for my JRuby 9k setup.

Comment: Since it's running in the JVM, most Java tools will do the job.

Comment: pry is _not_ MRI dependent! https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Thanks for the tip @deivid! I must have mixed up _pry_ and _pry-byebug_ (which is MRI-dependent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in https://rubygems.org/gems/pry/versions, there are many java versions of pry that work very well with jruby since jruby 1.6.

Pry is not MRI dependent. You can also use pry-remote in case your application is a web server or a rails app.

I've tried using byebug and gave up since it was not supported on jruby.

Answer (score 1):

The ruby-debug-ide-0.4.28 and ruby-debug-base-0.10.5.rc10-java gems seem to work with the intellij ruby plugin, using JRuby 9.0.0.0.rc2.